# Angular js ng-init on display block of an element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to call an angular controller function using ng-init once the element is visible...

Ex:

```
//Do not call function as element is hidden.
<div style="display: none" ng-init="function()"></div>

//Call function as element is visible.
<div style="display: block" ng-init="function()"></div>
```

How to check with ng-init and call function accordingly?

Comment: What makes the element visible? I don't see any Angular code for that. That's where you should call `function()`

Comment: `ng-init` is called as soon as the div is rendered, so use `ng-if` conditional statement to render or not render the div

Comment: @RGraham Its made visible in an external javascript file not in angular controller. Is there any way to watch for change of element style?

Comment: @Govan No. If it's external javascript, it should throw some sort of event. Use a directive and bind onto that event using `.on`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-if`

```
<div id="myDiv" ng-if="show" ng-init="init()"></div>
```

`ng-if` does not place the element into the DOM as long as its expression evaluates to false.

Demo: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/H173WL7jcXvbNEDEyA1n?p=preview)
(init function is run when div is shown after 2 seconds)

**EDIT:**

Apparently the display-property is set from outside of angular's context. I'm pretty sure it will be hard to make it work via the style attribute. The best suggestion I could come up with for that is to first get a reference to the div and then use `$apply` to make `ng-if`'s expression true.

With JQuery:

```
var scope = angular.element($('#myDiv')).scope();
scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.show = true;
});
```

That uses `angular.element` to get a reference to the scope, and then uses `$apply` to change a property in a way that will trigger Angular's dirty-checking and make the div appear.

Comment: This would be fine, but OP is using an external Javascript which sets the `display` property directly, so this won't work.

Comment: Right.. that part wasn't in the question when I started typing :)